# Does installing language pack in xp disable remote administration?

Tags: windows-xp

This must be a wierd question ;-)

I am going (from India) to work for my company branch in Germany and the problem is that they are using German version of XP.

We suggested installing English language pack. But the response from IT team was "We dont suggest that as it will disable remote administration".

This sounds funny to me. Is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if they mean the administrators remotely handling the machine would not be familiar with the changed language. Hence, they discourage it.

Comment: Yeah I felt the same but the word "disable" confused me.

Comment: Maybe their response itself got misrepresented in the translation `:-)`